# Having a hashmap add 1 for each instance of a string in an array.

Tags: java, arrays, foreach, hashmap

My hashmap class is as follows:

```
public HashMap<String, Integer> getWordCounts() {
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    String[] quoteOne = getWordArray();
    for (String stuff : quoteOne) {
        map.put(stuff, +1);
    }
    return map;
}
```

As it goes through quoteOne I want it to put each word from the array into the hashmap but for duplicates add 1 to the integer. e.g. "If you see this you are cool" would be put into the hashmap as

```
if  1
you 2
see 1
this 1
are 1
cool 1
```

But my code is outting it into the hashmap with you 1. What is wrong?

Comment: I didn't seen anything wrong?

Comment: I want it have the output as above when I put in the phrase indicated above but the output I am getting is 
    (if 1)
    (you 1)
    (see 1)
    (this 1)
    (are 1)
    (cool 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, for every word you see, you put +1 (the int value of positive 1).

You need to update the value, not override it.

```
for (String stuff : quoteOne) {
    Integer oldVal = map.get(stuff);
    if (oldVal == null) {
        oldVal = 0;
    }
    map.put(stuff, oldVal+1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop will be

```
 for (String stuff : quoteOne) {
     if(map.get(stuff) != null){
          int i = map.get(stuff);
          map.put(stuff,i+1)
        }else{
           map.put(stuff, 1);
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

HashMap replaces values if same key is provided.

From Java doc of HashMap#put

Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced.

Try something like this

```
for(String w : words) {
    Integer i = wordCounts.get(w);
    if(i == null) wordCounts.put(w, 1);
    else wordCounts.put(w, i + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        for(String i: quoteOne)
            map.put(i, (map.get(i)!=null)? map.get(i)+1:1);
```

Comment: Would you mind adding some description as to why this would work, where the asker's example wouldn't?